# access is denied exception when using Process.Start("excel.exe",FileName) to open an excel file

Tags: vb.net

We have a winforms application written in VB.Net that creates an excel file from a grid in the user's temporary folder and then opens the newly created file in Excel. This code has started to fail for one user only who gets an "access is denied" error when the application tries to open the newly created file in Excel.
If the user navigates to the temporary folder and double clicks on the newly created file it opens in Excel. The users of this application all belong to a domain and this behaviour has only recently started for one user running Windows10.

The code used is as below

```
   Private Sub btnExportExcel_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExportExcel.Click
        If MsgBox("Export details to excel spreadsheet?", MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel + MsgBoxStyle.Question) = MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
            Cursor = Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor
            Dim lcFileName As String = String.Format("{0}{1}.xlsx", System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid())
            PivotGridControl1.ExportToXlsx(lcFileName)
            Process.Start("EXCEL.EXE", lcFileName)
            Cursor = Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default
        End If
    End Sub
```

Tia Andy

Comment: Can you just `Process.Start(lcFileName)`? It looks like you're using the default opener. Setting the cursor is not that useful either.

Answer (score 0):

Is the local machine properly in the domain? The users might be, but I have seen process errors when the local PC is not part of the domain, or in a different AD group. Check the machine permissions to the temporary folder - when he double-clicks on the Excel file it is definitely his process, but that is not necessarily the case here.